# javascript: having issues with my library not loading before my code tries to use it

Tags: javascript

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/331982/Sandbox/comsat.html <-- code

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/331982/Sandbox/comsat.js <-- location of javascript file

So, This worked when I had everything all in one file, but I'm not a huge fan of having giant script tags in my HTML.

I get the error that one of the Raphael methods is undefined.... =\

How do I load my script correctly?

Everything is loaded in the `<head>`

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Comsat</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/331982/Sandbox/raphael-min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/331982/Sandbox/comsat.js"></script> 


  <style type="text/css">
    body{
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Ks6Pd.jpg);
}
  </style>

</head>
```

Comment: Those URLs aren't accessible to everyone; you should post a pared-down version of their contents.

Comment: shoot. I typed them wrong. EDIT: fixed. I can't really post a scaled down version of the code... cause I'm not really sure what the problem is. =\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the error is that `initPlayerSelect()` is not defined and I think that's because that function is not in the global scope, but rather it's defined inside another function scope and thus is not reachable from `initComSat()`.

You will need to make it so that `initPlayerSelect()` can be reached from inside the `initComSat()` function.

One way to do that is to move the `initPlayerSelect()` code out of the block it's in and put it right before `initComSat()`.

FYI, this particular error has nothing to do with using JS files or any order of JS files - it's purely a function scoping issue.

The next error I see is caused because you are running jQuery DOM access code before the page has been loaded here in comsat.js:

```
/*
    DOM Containers
*/
var cs_playerList = [];
var cs_players = $("ul.players");
// End DOM Containers
```

This code fails at script load time, which causes `cs_players` to be `null` or `undefined` which later causes `initPlayerSelect()` to fail.

Code like that can't be run until the page has been loaded.  jQuery has `$(document).ready()` to run code when the page is loaded.;

Comment: This is correct. And from what I can tell, `initComSat` is only global to support the inline `onload` event on the `<body>` tag. Listen for `load` from jQuery itself.

Comment: I fixed the initPlayerSelect() issue, but it appears that jQuery isn't loaded, as I get scrollwidth and children issues.

Comment: Now it looks to me like you have load ordering issues.  Not very easy to track these down from afar here without being able to work on the code.  If you are actually running any code as the code is being loaded (which is nice to avoid), then you will have to make sure scripts are loaded in the right order to satisfy dependencies.  If you are loading scripts dynamically (which it looks like you are), then you may have to wait for initialization until that loading has succeeded too.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Jacob said, you'll also want to listen for when the DOM is loaded. In that function, do your initialization. There are a number of utilities to do this, including the jQuery function. If you are using jQuery. So for instance, in jQuery that would look like this:

```
$( function()
{
  //initialize stuff here
});
```

Comment: maybe.. if you look at my updated html, you'll see that now jQuery isn't defined. =\